# display html form values in table in same page after submits

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

I get an error When I click on save button,then Data is saving is database but data is not showing in UI page inside table,Form Data value  show but hide immediately.

## Here is my code

```
<form action ="/EmployeesStatus/empformsubmit"method="post">
        <table>
        
         <tr id="rowid">
          <td> <input type="hidden" id="empemailid" name="empemailname" value="${showid}" readonly="readonly"> </td> 
          
          <td> <strong> PROJECT NAME </strong> </td>
          <td class="s1"> <select id="listid" name="projectlist" class="projid" style="width:165px;padding:3px;" onchange="GetSelectedTextValue(this)"></select> </td>
          
          <td> <strong> TASK NAME </strong> </td>
          <td class="s1"> <select id="taskid" name="tasklist" class="tasksid" style="width:165px;padding:3px;"> </select></td>  
          
          <td> <strong> COMPLETE HOURS </strong> </td>
          <td class="s1"> <input type="text" id="emphours" name="hours" class="completehrs"> </td> 
          
           <td> <strong> COMPLETE DATE </strong> </td>
           <td class="s1"> <input type="date" id="date" name="dates" style="width:165px"> </td> 
         </tr>
           
         <tr>
            <td> <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn1" /> </td> 
            <td> <input type="button" value="LOGOUT" onclick="logoutPage()" id="btn2"/></td>
            <td> <input type="button" value="VIEW TASK LIST" onclick="viewemployeetasklist()" id="btn3"/></td>
         </tr>
         
        </table>
        </form>
        
        <table border="2px" id="table1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <th> PROJECT ID </th>
                <th> TASK ID </th>
                <th> HOUR </th>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
        
            var tbdy = $('#table1').children('tbody');
            var tables = tbdy.length ? tbdy : $('#table1');
            var name111 = $('.projid').val();
            var email111 = $('.tasksid').val();
            var dob111 = $('.completehrs').val();
            $("#table1").show();
            tables.append('<tr><td>'+name111+'</td><td>'+email111+'</td> 
           <td>'+dob111+'</td></tr>');
           })
           </script>
```

I try to used jquery but didnt get a perfect solution

Thank u in advance.

Comment: "I get an error When I click on save button" What the error share it with us. "Data is saving is database" How? i don't see anny database related code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqGVEb is this any closer to what you're after? I assume you mean "hide immediately" is the page reloading when you click the submit button (I've added a `return false` to prevent this).

Answer (score 0):

While you submit the form the page is reload. Try to fire the submit event and prevent the reload.

Your question isn't really clear... If you want to show the data reached by the form submition, you could do that in this way:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    //YOUR CODE HERE

    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexdant91/f7Lmh1jd/2/

"I get an error When I click on save button" please share the error with us becouse we can't see any database related code.

Since your question it's not really clear, if it isn't what you need, tell us more.

Comment: Thanku you its really helpful for me

Comment: No problem! Good luck ;)